# Question closed with no link to reopen

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I found [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12941/which-when-exception-to-throw-if-property-is-null) question marked as closed.

It seemed to be asking a genuine question that seemed to be asking for best practices as defined in the [scope](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq).

Any particular reason it was closed? Also, no link to either edit it, or to vote for reopening. Is this because it is protected in some sense? Or is it that I am just missing the links for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the revision page of the question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/12941/revisions) it has been [locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) by Community♦.

It has seven deleted answers and it's and example code, not an actual code from a project. I think the latter was the reason of the close.

Comment: How did that happen? It does not seem to fit the criteria for locking.